# Element with multiple lines of text, how can I overflow them upwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsbin.com/dodiha/1/edit?html,css,js,output

So basically I have a "log" element that shows recent messages.  By default, it is collapsed and only 1 line-height high.  You can hover over it to make it taller.  The key is that it's anchored to the bottom of the page.  When I append text, I want to see it, not the first line.

So this is what it looks like:

```
---------------
| first line  |  visible
---------------
| second line |  hidden
| third  line |  hidden
```

And this is what I want it to look like:

```
| first  line |  hidden
| second line |  hidden
---------------
| third line  |  visible
---------------
```

I've tried every variant of "vertical-align" hoping that it would orient the text properly.  Obviously I can do prepend instead of append and it works for the collapsed view, but then when I expand the log window the messages are in reverse chronological order.  Think of it like a command prompt where the most recent messages are on the bottom and the top ones disappear but you can scroll up to see the history.

```js
function log(m) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + m + '</div>')
}
  
$("#add").on('click',function() {
  log("New Entry Added...")
})

$('#log').hover(
  function() {
        $('#log').animate({"height":"200px"})
  },
  function() {
    $('#log').animate({"height":"30px"})
  }
)

$(document).ready(function() {
  log('Document Ready.')
  
})
```

```css
#log {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 5px; right: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<button id="add">Add Entry</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way with minimal code change

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zwvgfkjo/

HTML:

```
  <div id="log">
    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="add">Add Entry</button>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#log {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 5px; right: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: bottom;
}
```

JS:

```
function log(m) {
  $('#log .wrapper').append('<div>' + m + '</div>');
}

$("#add").on('click',function() {
  log("New Entry Added...")
})

$('#log').hover(
  function() {
    $('#log').animate({"height":"200px"})
  },
  function() {
    $('#log').animate({"height":"30px"})
  }
)

$(document).ready(function() {
  log('Document Ready.')

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<div id="log-wrapper">
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#log {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```js
function log(m) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + m + '</div>')
}
  
$("#add").on('click',function() {
  log("New Entry Added...")
})

$('#log-wrapper').hover(
  function() {
        $('#log-wrapper').animate({"height":"200px"})
  },
  function() {
    $('#log-wrapper').animate({"height":"30px"})
  }
)

$(document).ready(function() {
  log('Document Ready.')
  
})
```

```css
#log-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 5px; right: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: bottom;
}
#log {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="log-wrapper">
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">Add Entry</button>
```