# Why won't this bottom-anchored element scroll text that overflowed up?

Tags: html, css

After having [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245206/element-with-multiple-lines-of-text-how-can-i-overflow-them-upwards#26245206) resolved, I attempted to add scrolling.  Only it doesn't work.

Basically, I have a log "window" that is bottom aligned (most recent messages at the bottom.  For some reason this makes overflow behave differently.  If I simply remove the "bottom: 0px" line below, it behaves as expected.

[Here is a jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/bohewo/1/edit)

**CSS**

```
#header {
  height: 200px;
}
#entityFooter {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#log {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="entityFooter">
    <div id="log" class="collapsed" style="">
      <div>This is a line in my log window</div>
      ...
      <div>This is a line in my log window</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either remove `position: absolute` from `#log` or add a fixed height. Absolute positioning removes the element from the flow of the document and causes it to behave differently

UPDATE

You could do this with jquery:

```
$('#entityFooter').scrollTop($('#entityFooter')[0].scrollHeight);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awmca63f/1/)

Comment: Doing either of those things means it is no longer anchored to the bottom of the wrapper.

Comment: i dont think im understanding what you're doing with the anchoring. And you have a fixed height on the parent `entityFooter` so why not just add one to `#log`

Comment: oh i get it now, the repeated text was throwing me off

Comment: Yeah, if you do your proposed solution, and remove all but a couple lines, you'll see it's at the top of the box instead of the bottom.